# Consistent Gmail Loading Features Problem

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, gmail

Frequently, I am confronted with a long loading time and a pop-up in Gmail that says some features can't be loaded. I have found the temporary solution to this problem - clear all of my personal data and it deletes the cookie that causes the error.  But I have come to have to do this now probably 2 times a day. I am running Google Chrome. Does anyone have an idea as to why I keep having this Gmail problem?

-Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem in Chrome; really strange!

Comment: Glad to know I'm not the only one. Started happening when I jumped to the "beta" version of Chrome.

Comment: Chrome on which OS? Win? OSX? Linux?

Comment: I am using Win 7 Professional

Comment: What's your internet connection like? I got this sometimes on dial-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that is an extension dealing with Chat, disable.

For me, the solution was to disable "Muzzle" extension.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any "Labs" features enabled?  I had this problem as well and had to play with disabling certain Labs features to get it working correctly.

Are you using the Dev channel? Perhaps you need to update.

Comment: Do you recall what Labs feature might've been the issue?

Comment: I'm using the latest dev build. The problem appears only on Chrome (sporadically), but never in Firefox, so labs features can't be responsible. It's probably Chrome, but why? It seems rather silly...

Comment: I am on the dev channel, it is completely updated. I do have many labs enabled though. I don't know which one is doing it though. Trial and error here would be very...unfortunate.

Comment: When *I* had this problem, I narrowed it down to something on the 'Undo Send' lab. 

Disabling that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may try disabling certain extensions in Chrome.

Personally, keyboard shortcuts and several other things in gmail broke when I began using "AdThwart" for blocking ads. Try disabling extensions and reloading to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Tack `&labs=0` onto the URL.  If there's no `?something` in the URL already, use `?labs=0` instead.  If there's a `#mark` in the URL, put this CGI parameter *before* that.

`labs=0` will disable all labs.  If this fixes it (very likely) then you know it's a lab.  If you track down the lab at fault, then complain in the support forums.  The Google Support folk will pick up on the volume of complaints and make the right people aware of the complaints ahd encourage a fix internally.

Answer (score 0):

I have similiar loading problems at school. What worked for me, was using https:// instead of just http://.

https://mail.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in dev chrome.  Disabling a bunch of labs features that I didn't use that much did it for me.