# Long lag and errors clicking gmail links in google chrome

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, gmail

I recently downloaded Google Chrome with Ubuntu 9.04 and love it.

Ironically one site I consistently have issues with is gmail. When I enter gmail I will click a link, say an email or the inbox link. After a very long wait (on the order of 30 seconds to a couple of minutes) my page will load with an error such as:

> Some Gmail features have failed to
>   load due to an Internet connectivity
>   problem. If this problem persists, try
>   reloading the page, using the older
>   version, or using basic HTML mode.
>   Learn More.

Googling the symptoms has not helped.

Has anyone else had any similar issues? Has anything helped?

Comment: see this one for some more: http://superuser.com/questions/84434/consistent-gmail-loading-features-problem

Answer (score 1):

i've encountered the same problem, but on a different os.

-Windows XP
-Chrome dev build

When loading gmail.com (even with lab=0) the site lags and presents errors. Html version does work, but thats not really a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you've enabled a Lab that is having issues. Try appending `?labs=0` to the url to turn of all labs; if that fixes the problem you can experiment with turning off individual labs to see if you can narrow down the problem